# Class with __iter__ that allows someone to call next() while also modifying the set

Tags: python, iteration, generator

```
class F:
    def __init__(self,int_set):
        self.set = int_set

    def __iter__(self):
        new_set = self.set
        for x in sorted(new_set):
            yield x
            new_set = self.aset
```

This works fine for the initial set. However I want to be able to iterate over mutations to the set while it is being iterated over using next()

Comment: This might seem like a good way to solve the problems you've faced with modifying something while you iterate over it, but defining exactly what happens to the iteration when you modify the set is surprisingly tricky. You end up needing it to do different things for different use cases, and it ends up creating more bugs than it solves. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: You're not really copying self.set when you assign it to new_set. If you iterate over a true shallow copy of the iterable, then I believe this problem is solvable. I also think you have a typo on the last line.

Comment: `self.set.copy()` may be what you want

Comment: `sorted` already makes a copy. The problem is making the iteration reflect changes to the set in a way that makes sense.

Comment: btw, `new_set = self.aset` does nothing useful. Once the for loop starts, its working on the iterator, not something else assigned to `new_set`.

Comment: @user2357112 is right. You should redesign the loop, not the set. Perhaps have a second set of recent additions that you create during the loop and merge them in after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at safe iteration over a mutating set:

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self, int_set):
        self.set = int_set

    def __iter__(self):
        seen = set()
        keep_going = True
        while keep_going:
            keep_going = False
            # iterate over as-yet-unseen items
            for item in self.set - seen:
                if item not in self.set:
                    # item removed from the set, skip it
                    continue
                yield item
                seen.add(item)
                keep_going = True
```

The idea is to loop over a copy of the set, with the following provisions:

- if an item was removed from the set during iteration, skip it;
- after exhausting all items, loop again, in order to cover new items having been added to the set (but ignoring duplicates);
- when no new items are seen, stop the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I know what is the problem with this but I'm still working on how to fix it. The problem is that you are using

```
new_set = self.set
```

This line assigns the original value of `self.set` to your `new_set`. While you are iterating with the `self.set`, the `new_set` will not be changed.